# Firebase iOS SDK crashes when used in Xcode frameworks

Tags: ios, firebase

I am trying to create a few common functions that read and write to Firestore in an Xcode framework so that they can be shared across a few a different apps. But the app crashes with

> The default FIRApp instance must be configured before the default
>   FIRAuthinstance can be initialized. One way to ensure that is to call
>   `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) in the App
>   Delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`
>   (`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in Swift).'

I am configuring Firebase in the main app with `FirebaseApp.configure()`. As soon as I move the file off the framework, the crash goes away. Is this expected to work?

Other details that might be relevant.

Xcode 11.2.1
Deployment target iOS 13.0

Comment: It looks like the app is trying to use FirebaseAuth before configuring Firebase ...

Comment: Hey @PaulBeusterien, that's not the case. Lifecycle events don't change between keeping Firebase code in the framework or keeping it in the app. But the app only crashes when the code is in the framework.

Comment: Which file do you mean when you say "move the file off the framework"?

Comment: any solution? @Prasanna

Comment: I got it working as described below. It would be interesting to hear if it works for you? @jlandyr

Comment: @AntPhitlok yes, I was initializing a FIRDATABASE object before the AppDelegate. I had to declare it as optional? and initialize it later

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is safe to call `FirebaseApp.configure()` from within your iOS framework (as long as you only call it once per framework). For example, create a static method inside a framework's class:

```swift
open class MyFramework {

    public static func configure() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }

}
```

Then call it from your App Delegate:

```swift
class AppDelegate ... {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunching...) {

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        MyFramework.configure()
    }
}
```